# In UIViewController's code, [self.subViewGrid setNeedsDisplay] not calling -drawRect

Tags: objective-c, uiview, cgcontext

I have an `iPad` app, using `Storyboards`, `XCode 4.6` and `iOS 6.1`.  I have a scene that contains a `UIViewController`.  Inside that `UIViewController`, I have a `UIScrollController`, all created using IB.  Programmatically, in `viewDidLoad` I created two (2) `UIViews` (one called `subViewGrid`, the other called `subViewData`) and added them to the `UIViewController`; they both display correctly in the Simulator.  Here's the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad  {

[super viewDidLoad];

// notify me when calendar has been tapped and CFGregorianDate has been updated
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(calendarTapNotification:)
                                             name:@"calendarDateSelected" object:nil ];

//   UIScrollVIew settings
CGSize scrollableSize = CGSizeMake(760, 1379);  //  set size of scheduleView
[self.schedScrollView setContentSize:scrollableSize];
self.schedScrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,44,44);  //  allow for scroll bar
self.schedScrollView.directionalLockEnabled = YES;  //  prevents diagonal scrolling

//  create a sub-view to hold the appointment GRID
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0,0,760,1390);  //  110,48,760,1390
subViewGrid = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
subViewGrid.tag = 12;  //  use tag to get correct sub-view
subViewGrid.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
subViewGrid.alpha = 1.0;  //  make it opaque
[self.schedScrollView addSubview:subViewGrid];

//  create a sub-view to hold the appointment DATA
frame = CGRectMake(110,48,670,750); 
subViewData = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
subViewData.tag = 22;  //  use tag to get correct sub-view
subViewData.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
subViewData.alpha = 0.2;  //  make it sort of transparent
[self.schedScrollView addSubview:subViewData];

[self.subViewGrid setNeedsDisplay];  //  ****  UPDATED ****
```

}

Here is the `.h` file contents for the `UIViewController`:

```
    @interface CalendarViewController : UIViewController  {

    UIView *subViewGrid;
    UIView *subViewData;

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *schedScrollView;

- (void) calendarTapNotification:(NSNotification *) notification;
-(NSDate *)beginningOfDay:(NSDate *)date;
-(NSDate *)endOfDay:(NSDate *)date;

@end
```

In my `drawRect` method, I have some code that is supposed to draw a "grid" on the subViewGrid.  The problem is `drawRect` never gets called.`

I have read the `UIView` Programmer's Guide and looked in SO and did a Google search, but found nothing that addresses the issue, which is: why won't `[self.subViewGrid setNeedsDisplay]` call `drawRect` from where I have it placed?

Comment: OK... I added two properties, one for subViewGrid and the other for subViewData, removing the declarations in the @interface code.  I added [self.subViewGrid setNeedsDisplay] in -viewDidLoad after all of the code that creates the two UIViews.  The method -drawRect did not get called.  Where am I supposed to put it?

Comment: I updated the code above to show where I put the [self.subViewGrid setNeedsDisplay];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an error in your reading the documentation. Understanding the documentation is critical for objective-C programming so I'll try to help you get a grasp of it.

If you look at the documentation for `setNeedsDisplay` you will see that it is either a `CALayer` or `UIView` class method. If you then look at inheritance, you will see that `UIView` is `UIResponder:NSObject` and `CALayer` is `NSObject`. None of these inherit from `UIViewController` which is why you are getting the error. You need to call `[self.subViewGrid setNeedsDisplay]`

Comment: Thank's to you, I found the answer.  I needed two (2) UIViews that I created in IB... once I had those, I created two classes, one for each view.  A simple matter of going to the correct class to do the drawing.  Thanks again...

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Is there an edit I could make to the answer to improve it for someone else who might stumble upon it?

Answer (score 3):

Your view controller needs to call `setNeedsDisplay` for the view it controls, not for itself.  So, you want

```
 [self.subViewGrid setNeedsDisplay]
```